# Django show only the values in the selected field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

So in my models.py I have this:

```
class Profesie(models.Model):
    titlu = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titlu

class Domeniu(models.Model):
    profesie = models.ForeignKey(Profesie)
    titlu = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titlu

class Anunt(models.Model):
    titlu = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='anunturi')
    profesie = models.ForeignKey(Profesie)
    domeniu = models.ForeignKey(Domeniu)
```

In the form when the user selects the field profesie, and then domeniu, for the domeniu field it should only display the values that are in the Profesie table. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: From what I understand you can't do this with Django alone, you need to use jquery or Ajax. You can search dynamic drop down list for some info but it doesn't look easy without knowing some JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about Jquery too. Thanks for the help :) If you can point me to any link with that I would appreciate

Comment: Take a look at [`jQuery change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) function.

Comment: Django Smart Selects is the usual package I see used for this: https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I found it eventually myself after a lot of searching, thanks for answering anyhow